# Using SQL Like Statement in MS Access DoCmd.OpenForm

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

Using MS Access, I am trying to search specific columns for strings. Using the WHERE argument of the DoCmd.OpenForm, I was able to get exact matches using "=".  However, I need to use LIKE instead, since the end users will need to have a more liberal filter.

The problem is that I keep getting an error when I use % or * in the string making up the SQL:

```
 stLinkCriteria = "[" & Combo_Filter_Name & "] Like %'" & Text_Filter_Name & "'%"
 DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName, acFormDS, , stLinkCriteria
```

What am I doing wrong? The following code I was using before works perfectly, but again, I need to use LIKE:

```
stLinkCriteria = "[" & Combo_Filter_Name & "] = '" & Text_Filter_Name & "'"
DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName, acFormDS, , stLinkCriteria
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the % sign is outside the quotes.

You have written %'mysearch'%

You should write '%mysearch%'

(Where mysearch is the string you are searching for)

You may need to use * instead of % for MS Access though.

Answer (score 2):

MS Access does not keep to the SQL standard, but uses `*` instead of `%` and `?` instead of `_` in `like`. See http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/like-operator-HP001032253.aspx